# Cheapest way to get Spring Attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, character-creation, optimization, e6

Spring Attack requires Dodge and Mobility, so the regular way to get it requires spending 3 feats.

I want to take the elocater prestige class as my 6th level in an E6 game. It requires Mobility and Spring Attack (but not Dodge per se, curiously enough).

Options I’m aware of for getting these cheaper:

- All three feats are available as bonus feats from various fighter variants (*Dragon* vol. 310). Monk can also get them via the Cobra Strike fighting style, though Spring Attack doesn’t happen until 6th. But that means monk 1st/fighter 2nd or monk 2nd/fighter 1st can get all three. Three levels is a **lot** to ask, though.
- Mobility can be gotten from magic *mobility* armor, a +1-equivalent special property (*Magic Item Compendium*). Timed right, that could replace one of the levels above.
- A *golden dancing peg leg* (*Dragon* vol. 318) conveniently grants Mobility **and** Spring Attack, but it inconveniently costs 55,000 gp. (Technically, *Dragon* vol. 351 has the *monkey head talisman* that also works, but that is considerably **more** expensive.)

Currently, my build is a half-elf cleric 1st/monk 2nd/ardent 1st/dragonmark heir 1st—and both monk bonus feats are, ideally, spoken for. The game has not yet started, so changes can still be made, but the race and levels are mostly inflexible. Half-elf is to qualify for the Mark of Storm. The monk levels, raging monk (*Dragon* vol. 310) to be precise, are there for berserker strength (brought up to that of a 6th-level barbarian via Chaos Rage), ardent 1st is there to be the manifesting that elocater advances, and dragonmark heir is the only way to access Lesser Dragonmark in E6.¹ Due to requirements, dragonmark heir has to be taken as my 5th overall character level.¹

Technically, a level or two of barbarian, druidic avenger, or rage cleric could replace a level or two of raging monk. Since I’m using both monk bonus feats, however, this is painful and probably not the best answer. Also, rage cleric conflicts with the level of cleric I was already planning on.

Speaking of, that level of cleric could *maybe* be dropped, but I would then need a feat (Touchstone or Planar Touchstone) to get a key cleric domain (Windstorm) via the *Catalogues of Enlightenment*, so that’s costly too.

Answers can be from any 3.*x*e source published by Wizards of the Coast (including electronic publications, e.g. PDFs or pages from wizards.com), or from any 3.*x*e issue of Dragon or Dungeon magazine. It must be 3.5e-legal, that is, if it’s 3.0e material it can’t have been replaced by 3.5e material (that likely nixes almost all of 3e psionics, though feel free to make the case for something that doesn’t explicitly reference mechanics that no longer exist). Epic material doesn’t exist in any way, shape, or form. Gaining levels and then losing them is banned, as are polymorph shenanigans. No messing with lycanthropy, level drain, gaining and losing templates, *reincarnate*, various rituals from *Savage Species* and elsewhere for changing one’s race, etc. *Manipulate form* is right out. Outside assistance is not preferred, and has to be level-appropriate—no assuming a 5th-level E6 character somehow knows a 7th-level psion or a 9th-level bard or what have you. For that matter, any and all sources of 4th-level-or-higher spells or powers are out, even though there are technically ways for E6 characters to access some of them. Magic items have to be producible by an E6 character, and cannot cost more than, say, 8,000 gp or so (I would gladly spend more than that saving a feat or two but I can’t justify having more than that as a 5th-level character). Items granting feats have to be actually published and existing—no positing a custom magic item that grants a key feat just because *Arms & Equipment Guide* suggests some guidelines for a DM who might want to create some. You cannot assume that leveling up will take place at any particular moment, so any temporary effects must be possible to keep up all day, every day—without Persist Spell.

1. <sub>Not strictly true, but any shenanigans that could achieve Lesser Dragonmark in E6 without using dragonmark heir, or allow dragonmark heir before 5th, are exactly the kinds of shenanigans that I’m avoiding.</sub>

Comment: Out of curiosity, why elocator? To this outsider, it seems much more trouble than it's worth and ain't bringing much to the table. I mean, *vanguard treads* (*MIC* 145) (3,100 gp; 2 lbs.) are within an E6 budget, and the *levitation* spell is available from a variety of sources. Is it just cool to float all the time? (By the way, can I just say I *hate* the disconnect between the elocator having as its requirements the Spring Attack feat and a base attack bonus of *+3*? I hate that. There. Said it. Thanks.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yup, just cool to float all the time. Good point about the BAB, though, that is rather dumb—it’s almost as if the PrC expects you to get these feats while skipping reqs, but aside from the *golden dancing peg leg*, I haven’t seen a way to do so.

Comment: Would your DM let you combine raging and martial monk (also from Dragon 310)? They're variants rather than ACFs, but they replace different features. Even if not, rage might be easier to get elsewhere than spring attack.

Comment: @Prevarications Raging monk doesn’t touch monk bonus feats, I could trivially use the Cobra Strike fighting style with it to get Dodge and Mobility. The real problem is that I had _already planned on_ uses for those bonus feats, so that doesn’t really buy me anything. Two levels of fighter, plus *mobility*, gets me there, but I don’t have two levels to play with. A level of fighter, and using a monk bonus feat for one, would work, except now the feat I was going to get with that monk bonus feat needs to be gotten elsewhere, and again I’m out of levels to use for it.

Comment: Martial monk lets you just take spring attack, and you can pick up mobility via armor. If your DM says martial monk needs to meet prereqs still (which it quite clearly doesn't, RAW), then yeah, it's not helpful.

Comment: @Prevarications I have never yet met a DM who actually allowed that, and I certainly would never suggest to any that they should. I would—and often do—just waive Dodge and Mobility prerequisites rather than allow that. But yes, RAW, that does provide a convenient avenue.

Comment: Martial monk is silly when you take two levels to pick up shock trooper + dire charge, but usually it's fine, like this elocator, or a Wis-based archer taking improved precise shot and so forth. I definitely encourage DMs to allow it, because it lets martials do neat things (whirlwind attack without crippling your build, for example), and leads to realizations about how preposterous many martial feat prereqs are. Martial monk can be too good, but so can second-level spells, and no one bans those just because *alter self* and *summon mirror mephit* exist.

Comment: How about becoming Dragonborn after you gain all the classes you want? It also requires Dex of 13 or 14 specifically. If those things are OK, I can make it into an answer after double-checking things.

Comment: @annoyingimp Not sure how that would help, since dragonborn doesn’t grant any feats, or otherwise help here? Anyway, _Races of the Dragon_ specifically notes that dragonmarked characters who become dragonborn lose their dragonmarks and have to choose new feats, which means it’s a no-go for me.

Comment: The thig is about losing Dex and, since you no more qualify for Dodge, swapping it for anything you want for free (as well as other feats, dependant on Dex, or Dodge, etc.) The issue with dragonmarks is among things, which were in need of re-reading. Sure, it ruins my plan.

Comment: @annoyingimp Losing prereqs doesn’t entitle you to replace those features, in general. Does the Rite of Rebirth specifically note that?

Comment: It does. "If you no longer qualify for a feat due to the transformation, you lose the feat and immediately select a new feat for which you qualify in its place. You must also replace any feat for which the lost feat was a prerequisite."

Comment: @annoyingimp Interesting, missed that.

Comment: It may be too late, but seeing as there are no answers, can you explain why Mark of Storm is critical for your build? Is it fluff-inspired? Or is 1/day SLA so good? I'm only briefly familiar with Eberron, so I can easily skip things. Maybe, you can replace it with similar benefit from another source?

Comment: @annoyingimp Unlock Dragonmark plus shenanigans for infinite action points, so I can use all the SLAs at-will, even those I had not chosen. Which still isn’t stellar, really, particularly when Greater Dragonmark isn’t on the table, but it is what I’m trying to optimize. So no, can’t be replaced.

Comment: It's too bad that E6 will not let you pick up *Psionic Plane Shift* and *Psionic Teleport* as 3rd level powers, since that's an Elocator 6 class feature.

Comment: Are you allowed (or willing) to use A&EG? Of course, coming up with 10k-30k in spare gold is likely to be somewhat problematic....

Comment: @nijineko Specific items, yes. The generic suggestion that maybe a DM might allow feats to be purchased, no.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, with *mobility* armor from Magic Item Compendium you could avoid wasting a feat on Mobility. And, if you want to get any wattage out of your Spring Attack, pick up Dodge, perhaps through a Bloodline?

## Bloodlines

[Bloodlines](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/races/bloodlines.htm) are a thing, if your DM allows them. The Major Devil bloodline, in particular, gives you Dodge at level 2, or level 4 if you take it as Intermediate. Some extra XP costs involved, of course.

## Fractional BaB

With fractional BaB (Unearthed Arcana, p. 73), you count each of your levels as either +1, +0.75 or +0.5, depending on how the class progresses BaB, rather than +1 or +0.

So, you would have 1 level of Cleric, 2 levels of Monk, 1 of Ardent and 1 of Dragonmark Heir, all 3/4 BaB classes, so +0.75 each. This leaves us at +3.75, which is better than the non-fractional +1, but...

> In general, if you wind up with a fraction, round down, even if the fraction is one-half or larger.

So RAW you won't get the prerequisites for picking the Spring Attack feat in time. This is a case where you'd have to rely on the tender mercies of your DM, by allowing rounding up of +3.75 to +4.

Your best bet seems to be giving up on Cleric, leaving you at four levels of +0.75, or +3 BaB. A level of any full-BaB class gives you +4 BaB at character level 5, so taking your fifth character level as Fighter both fulfills all requirements (provided the Bloodline and armor enhancement) for Spring Attack, as well as a Bonus Fighter feat, a list which includes Spring Attack.

- Dodge: Bloodline
- Mobility: *mobility* armor
- Spring Attack: Fighter bonus feat

...and when you reach level 6, you'd fulfill all requirements for Elocater, provided you ranked up Concentration enough.

### Nota Bene

*Don't* expect the cost for Bloodlines to be as cheap as RAW can read them.

Still, Bloodlines + *mobility* enchantment gets rid of both non-BaB requirements for Spring Attack. BaB is harder, with the class levels you are otherwise planning for, so a level of Fighter seems to be your best bet.

<strike>Marshal</strike>

<strike>Retraining</strike>

## Fluff it

<strike>Kalashtar</strike>

### Bloodlines are out?

In the Eberron Campaign Setting (p. 290), the Empty Vessel "host race" is described as:

> Unwilling to permanently join with
> a human host as the kalashtar did, the quori sought another
> solution. That solution was to use controlled breeding and
> psionic manipulation to spawn highly evolved Riedran
> humans tinged with elf and fiendish blood.

So Empty Vessels are explicitly defined as part human, part elf - that sounds like a half-elf to me. They are naturally psionic, but have no 1st level powers they can naturally manifest, so the Ardent level is required and the Cleric level is lost. However, they do get a Bonus Feat at level 1, so Dodge is "free".

### This is fluff

This is a fluffy appeal to your DM, and not a straight-forward rules-as-written argument. It depends on your DM's willingness to support a concept that's stretching the boundaries of "Dragonmarked" beyond where some may be willing.

## Martial Monk

If you can sacrifice one of your two Monk bonus feats, the Martial Monk variant class from Dragon #310, p. 45, offers an opportunity.

> **Gain**: Fighter bonus feat list to choose monk bonus feats (at 1st, 2nd and 6th level; Intimidate is class skill.
>
> **Lose**: -1 skill point per level (and -4 skill points at 1st level); no Knowledge skills as class skills.

Combine this with the regular rules for Monk bonus feats:

> **Bonus Feat**: [...] *A monk need not have any of the prerequisites normally required for these feats to select them*.

...well, again, Spring Attack is on the list of Fighter Bonus Feats, so Spring Attack at level 2, why not?

Comment: Gonna need more than “it doesn’t say you can’t” for the marshal bonus feat. “It says you can’t everywhere else” doesn’t actually mean anything; that could well be reminder text or for emphasis. Also won’t touch bloodlines with a 10-foot pole, but that’s on me since it’s not mentioned in the question...

Comment: The traditional argument for bonus feats not needing prereqs by default is that "bonus feat" has general rules *only* in the Monster Manual (page 301, top of the righthand column). In a discussion of what to do if a monster doesn't have feat pre-reqs, MM states "consider altering the creature so it qualifies for the feat, or assign the feat as a bonus feat. (It is acceptable for a creature to have a bonus feat for which it does not meet the prerequisites.)"

Comment: @Kryan Personally, I have never seen anyone actually try this. I would probably allow it if they did (perhaps with line-item vetoes for Leadership or Epic Spellcasting or similar).  The classes that get unlimited bonus feats tend to be the classes that are running hard just to keep up. Besides, I kind of like the idea that you never have any idea what one weird trick a high-level rogue can throw at you.

Comment: @KRyan Added a paragraph on Retraining/Rebuilding.

Comment: Retraining and rebuilding can’t be used to achieve a build that couldn’t have been achieved without them. “The most basic level of character revision is retraining—that is, adjusting a decision you made earlier in your character’s career by selecting a different **legal** option,” “If reallocating your character’s class levels disqualifies him for a prestige class in which he already has one or more levels, he loses the benefit of any class features or other special abilities granted by that prestige class.”

Comment: "So a Marshal who already has Skill Focus (Diplomacy) can choose a different feat, which could conceivably be any feat" 
This is straight up wrong. You DO need prerequisites unless specified otherwise.

Comment: @Snappie Decidedly debatable: https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?421607-Bonus-Feats-amp-Prerequisites

Comment: Half the point of the level of ardent is _to have ardent manifesting to advance with elocater._ “Saving” that level doesn’t actually save me anything.

Comment: @KRyan So how about that Empty Vessel, and buying off the +1 LA?

Comment: I don’t buy that it qualifies for the feat, and I don’t play with LA buy-off (or LA, for that matter), so it doesn’t really help me.

Comment: @KRyan It seems you are excluding rather more 3.x material than the Question states, you might want to clarify.

Comment: @From "Your character must have the indicated ability score, class feature, feat, skill, base attack bonus, or other quality designated in order to select or use that feat" ~PHB page 87. These are the general rules for feats that apply to ALL feats unless specified otherwise. The rules are crystal clear, stop trying to seed a gray area where there isn't one.

Comment: @Snappie I'm presenting options to KRyan, noting where they're suspect. Check the "Nota Bene" paragraph (originally the final paragraph) for my own thoughts on that interpretation.

Comment: I’m not inclined to edit the question out from under you; I’ll keep these caveats in mind for future questions, but since I didn’t mention them, I’m not objecting to your answer on those grounds. That said, they **are** variants, so they really can’t be assumed—but then so are the _UA_ alternate class features and variant classes, which are routinely assumed. In my experience, LA buy-off is not uncommon, but not “the norm,” and bloodlines are used by almost no one (because they’re an incoherent mess that add nothing useful to the game and only cause headaches).

Comment: But I only bring those up as side-notes. The real problems I have with this answer are simply that I do not agree that either marshal or empty vessel qualify for the things you claim they do.

Comment: I happened upon this question again, and I feel I was much too generous in my previous comments. This answer is simply wrong. Every “option” presented isn’t, actually, a legal option—not by RAW, nor by any other metric short of “ask your DM to do you a favor.” Which makes none of this answer useful or valuable—in fact, it makes this answer actively damaging in that readers might _think_ any part of it is correct. As far as I can tell, none of it is. Your “nota bene” is wrong—this is not RAW.

Comment: @KRyan Oh? Bloodlines + mobility enhancement is not a valid, RAW way to qualify for Spring Attack, without further investment of (actual) levels or feats?

Comment: You changed your answer since my comment, and no, I don’t think it’s valid to assume the use of a variant rule no one uses because it is incomprehensible, nor do I think any “interpretation” of that rule is valid because the rules text is, again, incomprehensible. _No one_ agrees on how bloodlines work.

Comment: @KRyan I cut away the Marshal and Kalashtar parts of the answer, and rewrote the remaining to reflect the exclusion. Bloodlines have been present from the get-go, and the Bloodlines alternative, Empty Vessels, since well before your last comment.

Comment: @KRyan I was doing a random Monk build and found a new idea for you.

Answer (score 0):

Play a LA +2 Entomanothropy as a small Snow Spider and reduce your Level Adjustment from 2 to 1 at 6th (1 racial HD + 3 class levels + 2 level adjustment = 6).

You are now 5th level with 1 racial HD, 1 Level Adjust, and 3 class levels with Spring Attack.

You may lose some point buy (see the E6 level adjustment link below) or your GM may use the DMG's page 172 rules for Level Adjustment. You will have +2 WIS -2 INT -4 STR +4 DEX to make up for some lost point buy.

You still retain feats and skills from your 1 level of racial, you just lose feats/skills from the final one level adjustment you can't buy off until level 7. Which wont happen in E6.

Entomanothropy
https://web.archive.org/web/20050302192431/http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/re/20040621a

Small Snow Spider https://www.realmshelps.net/monsters/block/Snow_Spider,_Small

Level Reducing https://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/races/reducingLevelAdjustments.htm

E6 LA https://dungeons.fandom.com/wiki/E6_(3.5e_Sourcebook)/Rules#Races_with_a_Level_Adjustment